# Does boost::any save a copy or reference/pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

Is the following code safe?

```
boost::any any_value;

{
    std::string s = "HelloWorld";
    any_value = s;
}

std::string ss = any_cast<std::string>(any_value);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) docs:

```
template<typename ValueType> any & operator=(const ValueType & rhs);
```

> Makes a copy of rhs, discarding previous content, so that the new
>   content of is equivalent in both type and value to rhs.

So yes, it's safe to do that. A copy of the string is stored, not a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. `boost::any` takes everything by making a copy of it, assuming the type fulfills the `Copyable` concept.